# Second monitor on NVidia card cannot detect proper resolution

Tags: nvidia, 12.04, resolution, monitor

A friend had given me one of his extra monitors, and even in Windows it gave me trouble in producing the right resolutions. I switched back to Ubuntu with the release of Pangolin but can't get it to work as a second monitor.

The monitor is a ViewSonic VX2235WM and supposed to operate at 1680x1050. It is plugged into the second (VGA) port of my NVidia 9400GT 1GB. I tried playing with xrandr and cvt, and while I can seemingly get modeline information for the desired resolution, I can't get it to acknowledge this as a resolution.

After trying cvt and xrandr, I kicked around in nvidia-settings, to no avail. I attempted replacing my (empty) default xorg.conf with a fresh one put together by nvidia-xconfig, but it too has given me no headway.

Not sure what other information you would need, here is my xorg.conf:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 295.40  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-06.nvidia.com)  Thu Apr  5 22:40:54 PDT 2012

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection
[... took out the InputDevice sections to make it all fit...]
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 65.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    Modeline       "1680x1050" 119.00 1680 1728 1760 1840 1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option         "ModeValidation" "NoMaxPClkCheck"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I made two changes to it based on suggestions found here and other places on the internet; The modeline is mine, the ModeValidation option in Device is mine, and I upped the HorizSync just in case. None of which seemed to have the effect I had hoped for.

The Xorg.0.log, just in case:

```
[   764.066] 
X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
[   764.066] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   764.066] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.24-29-server x86_64 Ubuntu
[   764.066] Current Operating System: Linux broodmother 3.2.0-24-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 08:43:22 UTC 2012 x86_64
[   764.067] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic root=UUID=5d056ee3-8b6f-49c1-8934-f3b77b8ffbe4 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[   764.067] Build Date: 05 April 2012  04:32:37AM
[   764.067] xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   764.067] Current version of pixman: 0.24.4
[   764.067]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   764.067] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   764.067] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Apr 27 00:21:50 2012
[   764.067] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[   764.067] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   764.068] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[   764.068] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[   764.068] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[   764.069] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[   764.069] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[   764.069] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[   764.069] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   764.069] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   764.069] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   764.069]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   764.069] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   764.069]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   764.069] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   764.069]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   764.069] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   764.069]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   764.069] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   764.069]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   764.069] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" does not exist.
[   764.069]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   764.069] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[   764.069] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   764.069] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[   764.069] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[   764.069] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[   764.069] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f47c414fb00
[   764.069] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   764.069]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   764.069]    X.Org Video Driver: 11.0
[   764.069]    X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
[   764.069]    X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
[   764.071] (--) PCI:*(0:2:0:0) 10de:0641:196e:0562 rev 161, Mem @ 0xfa000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/536870912, 0xf8000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000bc00/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[   764.071] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[   764.071] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[   764.072] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[   764.073] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   764.073]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[   764.073]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[   764.073]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[   764.073] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   764.073] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   764.073] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[   764.073] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[   764.073] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[   764.073] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   764.073] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[   764.073] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[   764.074] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[   764.074] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   764.074]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[   764.074]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[   764.074]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[   764.074] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   764.074] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   764.074] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[   764.090] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   764.090]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[   764.090]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[   764.090] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  295.40  Thu Apr  5 21:57:38 PDT 2012
[   764.090] (II) Loading extension GLX
[   764.090] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[   764.091] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[   764.091] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   764.091]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.13.0
[   764.091]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[   764.091]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[   764.091] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[   764.091] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[   764.091] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[   764.091] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   764.091]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[   764.091]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[   764.091] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[   764.091] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[   764.091] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[   764.091] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   764.091]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.2.0
[   764.091]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[   764.091] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[   764.091] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[   764.091] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[   764.092] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   764.092]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[   764.092]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   764.092] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  295.40  Thu Apr  5 21:38:35 PDT 2012
[   764.092] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[   764.092] (++) using VT number 7

[   764.092] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   764.092] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   764.092] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[   764.093] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   764.093]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[   764.093]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   764.093] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[   764.093] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[   764.093] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[   764.093] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   764.093]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[   764.093]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   764.093] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[   764.093] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[   764.093] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[   764.093] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[   764.093] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[   764.093] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[   764.093] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[   764.093] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[   764.093] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   764.093] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   764.093] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "ModeValidation" "NoMaxPClkCheck"
[   764.093] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[   765.391] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-1
[   765.471] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VH222H (DFP-0)) does
[   765.471] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     not support NVIDIA 3D Vision stereo.
[   765.473] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce 9400 GT (G96) at PCI:2:0:0 (GPU-0)
[   765.473] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 1048576 kBytes
[   765.473] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 62.94.61.00.51
[   765.473] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[   765.473] (--) NVIDIA(0): Interlaced video modes are supported on this GPU
[   765.475] (--) NVIDIA(0): Connected display device(s) on GeForce 9400 GT at PCI:2:0:0
[   765.475] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-1
[   765.475] (--) NVIDIA(0):     Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VH222H (DFP-0)
[   765.475] (--) NVIDIA(0): CRT-1: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   765.475] (--) NVIDIA(0): Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VH222H (DFP-0): 330.0 MHz
[   765.475] (--) NVIDIA(0):     maximum pixel clock
[   765.475] (--) NVIDIA(0): Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VH222H (DFP-0): Internal Dual
[   765.475] (--) NVIDIA(0):     Link TMDS
[   765.525] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[   765.526] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VH222H (DFP-0) (Using
[   765.526] (**) NVIDIA(0):     EDID frequencies has been enabled on all display
[   765.526] (**) NVIDIA(0):     devices.)
[   765.526] (II) NVIDIA(0): Mode Validation Overrides for Ancor Communications Inc ASUS
[   765.526] (II) NVIDIA(0):     VH222H (DFP-0):
[   765.526] (II) NVIDIA(0):     NoMaxPClkCheck
[   765.590] (II) NVIDIA(0): Assigned Display Device: DFP-0
[   765.590] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[   765.590] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[   765.590] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[   765.590] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[   765.590] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated modes:
[   765.590] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "nvidia-auto-select"
[   765.590] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1920 x 1080
[   765.620] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (103, 105); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[   765.620] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[   765.620] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[   765.620] (II) NVIDIA: Using 768.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory access.
[   765.624] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[   765.662] (II) Loading extension NV-GLX
[   765.697] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[   765.697] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store disabled
[   765.697] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[   765.698] (**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[   765.698] (II) Loading extension NV-CONTROL
[   765.698] (II) Loading extension XINERAMA
[   765.698] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[   765.698] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[   765.698] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[   765.698] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   765.698]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.2.0
[   765.698]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[   765.698] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[   765.698] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[   765.698] (==) RandR enabled
[   765.698] (II) Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[   765.698] (II) Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[   765.698] (II) Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[   765.698] (II) Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[   765.698] (II) Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[   765.698] (II) Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[   765.698] (II) Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[   765.698] (II) Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[   765.698] (II) Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[   765.698] (II) Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[   765.698] (II) Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[   765.698] (II) Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[   765.698] (II) Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[   765.698] (II) Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[   765.698] (II) Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[   765.698] (II) Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[   765.700] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[   765.715] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[   765.718] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[   765.718] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   765.718] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[   765.718] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[   765.718] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   765.718]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 2.7.0
[   765.718]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   765.718]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 16.0
[   765.718] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[   765.718] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[   765.718] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   765.718] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[   765.719] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[   765.719] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[   765.719] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[   765.719] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1/event1"
[   765.719] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[   765.719] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   765.719] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   765.719] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   765.719] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "intl"
[   765.720] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-A5431D4A34463C892C9E905E2E421B30A3CC30DD.xkm
[   765.721] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[   765.721] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   765.721] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[   765.721] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[   765.721] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   765.721] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[   765.721] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[   765.721] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[   765.721] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[   765.721] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[   765.721] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[   765.721] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   765.721] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   765.721] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   765.721] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "intl"
[... Took out info about the Logitech USB Reciever to make it all fit... ]
[   765.724] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   765.724] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   765.724] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   765.724] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "intl"
[   765.724] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: initialized for relative axes.
[   765.724] (WW) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: ignoring absolute axes.
[   765.724] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[   765.724] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[   765.724] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   765.724] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   765.725] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Keyboard (/dev/input/event4)
[   765.725] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   765.725] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech USB Keyboard'
[   765.725] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[   765.725] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard: always reports core events
[   765.725] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[   765.725] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Vendor 0x46d Product 0xc31c
[   765.725] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Found keys
[   765.725] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[   765.725] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/usb4/4-4/4-4:1.0/input/input4/event4"
[   765.725] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[   765.725] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   765.725] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   765.725] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   765.725] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "intl"
[   765.725] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Keyboard (/dev/input/event5)
[   765.725] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   765.725] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech USB Keyboard'
[   765.725] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[   765.725] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard: always reports core events
[   765.725] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event5"
[   765.725] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Vendor 0x46d Product 0xc31c
[   765.725] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Found absolute axes
[   765.725] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Forcing absolute x/y axes to exist.
[   765.725] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Found keys
[   765.725] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Configuring as mouse
[   765.725] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[   765.725] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/usb4/4-4/4-4:1.1/input/input5/event5"
[   765.725] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[   765.725] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   765.725] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   765.725] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   765.725] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "intl"
[   765.726] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: initialized for absolute axes.
[   765.726] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[   765.726] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[   765.726] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   765.726] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   765.726] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Microsoft LifeChat LX-3000  (/dev/input/event6)
[   765.726] (**) Microsoft LifeChat LX-3000 : Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   765.726] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Microsoft LifeChat LX-3000 '
[   765.726] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[   765.726] (**) Microsoft LifeChat LX-3000 : always reports core events
[   765.726] (**) evdev: Microsoft LifeChat LX-3000 : Device: "/dev/input/event6"
[   765.726] (--) evdev: Microsoft LifeChat LX-3000 : Vendor 0x45e Product 0x70f
[   765.726] (--) evdev: Microsoft LifeChat LX-3000 : Found keys
[   765.726] (II) evdev: Microsoft LifeChat LX-3000 : Configuring as keyboard
[   765.726] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/usb4/4-5/4-5:1.3/input/input6/event6"
[   765.726] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Microsoft LifeChat LX-3000 " (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[   765.726] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   765.726] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   765.726] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   765.726] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "intl"
[   765.727] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia Rear Mic (/dev/input/event10)
[   765.727] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   765.727] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   765.727] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia Front Headphone (/dev/input/event11)
[   765.727] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   765.727] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   765.727] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia Line-Out CLFE (/dev/input/event12)
[   765.727] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   765.727] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   765.727] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia Line-Out Surround (/dev/input/event13)
[   765.727] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   765.727] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   765.728] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia Line-Out Front (/dev/input/event14)
[   765.728] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   765.728] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   765.728] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia Line (/dev/input/event8)
[   765.728] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   765.728] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   765.728] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia Front Mic (/dev/input/event9)
[   765.728] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   765.728] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   766.279] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "1920x1080_60_0"
[   779.677] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-27B6B510261BF6E4ADB20ED0604835AE1EA5A001.xkm
[   798.384] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode
[   798.384] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-0:1920x1080_60_0@1920x1080+0+0,CRT-1:1360x768@1360x768+1920+0"
```